# parseFloat gson json string

Tags: json, jsp, servlets, command, gson

I have a problem displaying values as float when serializing/deserializing from and to json with gson. Instead it removes the floating points, so instead of displaying fx. 745.0 is displays 745. any idea why?
Here is the backend code being generated through a command pattern:

```
public String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, CurrencyClient client) {

    String currency = client.findAll_JSON(String.class);

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    Currency[] currencies = gson.fromJson(currency, Currency[].class); 
    System.out.println("currencies " + currencies[0].getRate());
    response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter()) {
        //System.out.println("JSON " + currencies);

        MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
        for (Object c : currencies) {
           myObject.add((gson.toJson(c)));
        }
        System.out.println("value of rate: " + gson.toJson(myObject.getCurrencies()));
        pw.println(gson.toJson(myObject)); 

        pw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return super.execute(request);
}
```

}

class MyObject {

```
ArrayList<Object> currencies = new ArrayList<Object>();

public MyObject() {
}
public void add(Object e){
    this.currencies.add(e);
}
public Object getCurrencies() {
    return currencies;
}

public void setCurrencies(ArrayList<Object> currencies) {
    this.currencies = currencies;
}
```

And the client side code:

```
            $(document).ready(function() {



                    $.ajax({

                        url: "Controller", 
                        cache: false,
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {command: 'getCurrencyRates'}, 
                        success: function(data) { 

                            $.each(data.currencies, function(index, value) { 

                              var v = JSON.parse(value);  


                                console.log(rate);

                                $("<tr><td>" + v.code + "</td><td>" + v.description + "</td><td>" + v.rate + "</td></tr>")
                                        .appendTo($("table"));
                            });
                        }

                    });
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript only has a single numeric type called `Number`. It holds the same range as the Java `double` type. The same goes for JSON.

When you concatenate the value with a string the `toString()` method is called on the number. How [Number.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) works is defined in **9.8.1 ToString Applied to the Number Type** in [the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).

Basically, it will not print decimal places if they are not significant. From the console:

```
> 1234.0000.toString()
"1234"
```

If you are formatting currency for display, you need to think in terms of strings. You'll need something like [this plugin](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/) for jQuery if you do this on the client or see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberintro.html) for Java.

Comment: I can just use v.rate.toFixed(2)